# Mailer Error: The following From address failed: no-reply@xxxx.fr : Called Mail() without being connected

Tags: php, email, debian, phpmailer

After an apt-get purge openssl during the installation of nagios nrpe plugin.

My postgresql cluster got removed. So i reinstalled all of it from my backups.

So now everything is working but my applications are not sending mail anymore.

I'am using PHPMailer in order to send mail. Everthing worked fine before and the configuration script has not changed.

Now here is the message i got while trying to send mail from the applications :

```
Mailer Error: The following From address failed: no-reply@xxxx.fr :
Called Mail() without being connected
```

We are on debian 8 jessie, Postgresql 9.4, php5, apache 2.4

Comment: Code? Have you read the docs? Where's your debug output? What mail server are you using?

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, we are using posfix, the debug output from apache ?

Comment: No, from PHPMailer - read the docs https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Ok problem solved, during apt-get remove openssl, the program ca-certificates got removed.

Comment: so just did apt-get install ca-certificates and mail sending worked.